# The term 'Get-SPOList' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have this script and when I execute it, I get the below error.

> The term 'Get-SPOList' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program.Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again.

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://xxxxxxxxxxx

$web = Get-SPOWeb

Get the source list
$sourceList = Get-SPOList -Identity xxx

Get the destination list 
$destinationList = Get-SPOList -Identity xxxx

Get all items with a "Closed" status from the source list 
$items = Get-SPOListItem -List $sourceList | Where-Object {$_["Status"] -eq "Closed"} 

Add each item to the destination list 
foreach ($item in $items) { Add-SPOListItem -List $destinationList -Values $item.FieldValues 

Remove the item from the source list 
Remove-SPOListItem -Identity $item -Force }
```

The script copies items from a Source List to Destination List.

However this error happens that the cmdlet is not recognized.

I tried installing the `SharePoint Powershell Module` and `PnP SharePoint Online Powershell Module` but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Get-SPOList does not exist. You can search for a full list of all available cmdlets here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/connect-sposervice?view=sharepoint-ps

regarding the Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell namespace

Comment: Do you know any alternative to Get-SPOList?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the cmdlet `Get-SPOList` does not exists on any of the PS modules.
This can be easily seen by going over to [Powershell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) and querying the below `Cmdlets:"Get-SPOList"` will get you 0 results.

[image: powershellgallery results]

You might have missed a step or two of the tutorial in order to copy list items from one list to another.

Secondly, the `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell Module` is mostly needed to perform Administration-oriented tasks on the SPO and the tenant behind it. You will not be able to find cmdlets that will help you with your task from this PS Module.

Lastly, a simple copy-paste script for the list items of a source list to a destination list could be the below, [taken from SharePointDiary's blog](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/01/sharepoint-online-copy-list-items-to-another-list-using-powershell.html#:%7E:text=PnP%20PowerShell%20to,copy%20list%20items%3A), which by the way, you can read through in order to help you with your task:

```
        #Get All Items from the Source List in batches 
        Write-Progress -Activity "Reading Source..." -Status "Getting Items from Source List. Please wait..."
        $SourceListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $SourceListName -PageSize 500
        $SourceListItemsCount= $SourceListItems.count
        Write-host "Total Number of Items Found:"$SourceListItemsCount       
 
        #Get fields to Update from the Source List - Skip Read only, hidden fields, content type and attachments
        $SourceListFields = Get-PnPField -List $SourceListName | Where { (-Not ($_.ReadOnlyField)) -and (-Not ($_.Hidden)) -and ($_.InternalName -ne  "ContentType") -and ($_.InternalName -ne  "Attachments") }
     
        #Loop through each item in the source and Get column values, add them to target
        [int]$Counter = 1
        ForEach($SourceItem in $SourceListItems)
        {  
            $ItemValue = @{}
            #Map each field from source list to target list
            Foreach($SourceField in $SourceListFields)
            {
                #Check if the Field value is not Null
                If($SourceItem[$SourceField.InternalName] -ne $Null)
                {
                    #Handle Special Fields
                    $FieldType  = $SourceField.TypeAsString
 
                    If($FieldType -eq "User" -or $FieldType -eq "UserMulti" -or $FieldType -eq "Lookup" -or $FieldType -eq "LookupMulti") #People Picker or Lookup Field
                    {
                        $LookupIDs = $SourceItem[$SourceField.InternalName] | ForEach-Object { $_.LookupID.ToString()}
                        $ItemValue.add($SourceField.InternalName,$LookupIDs)
                    }
                    ElseIf($FieldType -eq "URL") #Hyperlink
                    {
                        $URL = $SourceItem[$SourceField.InternalName].URL
                        $Description  = $SourceItem[$SourceField.InternalName].Description
                        $ItemValue.add($SourceField.InternalName,"$URL, $Description")
                    }
                    ElseIf($FieldType -eq "TaxonomyFieldType" -or $FieldType -eq "TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti") #MMS
                    {
                        $TermGUIDs = $SourceItem[$SourceField.InternalName] | ForEach-Object { $_.TermGuid.ToString()}                    
                        $ItemValue.add($SourceField.InternalName,$TermGUIDs)
                    }
                    Else
                    {
                        #Get Source Field Value and add to Hashtable
                        $ItemValue.add($SourceField.InternalName,$SourceItem[$SourceField.InternalName])
                    }
                }
            }
            Write-Progress -Activity "Copying List Items:" -Status "Copying Item ID '$($SourceItem.Id)' from Source List ($($Counter) of $($SourceListItemsCount))" -PercentComplete (($Counter / $SourceListItemsCount) * 100)
         
            #Copy column value from source to target
            $NewItem = Add-PnPListItem -List $TargetListName -Values $ItemValue
 
            Write-Host "Copied Item ID from Source to Target List:$($SourceItem.Id) ($($Counter) of $($SourceListItemsCount))"
            $Counter++
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`get-SPOList` is part of the Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell powershell module available in the PowerShell Gallery. To install:

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

To install for current user only (when you do not have admin privileges):

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -Scope CurrentUser
```

Comment: It's not even in the package details here : https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell/16.0.23109.12000

Are you confusing it with "Get-SPOListDesign"?

Comment: Hi. I tried to run the command but I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: No, I am not confusing, I am trying to retrieve the list.