# Powershell code for sharepoint files named readers

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have Sharepoint online management and when I run my code it returns an error as below

```
Get-SPOFile : The term 'Get-SPOFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:6 char:10
$files = Get-SPOFile -Site $site
CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-SPOFile:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
   FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried debugging by putting print after each command

```
       # Get the SharePoint site
       $siteUrl = "https://example.com"
       $site = Get-SPOSite $siteUrl
       Write-Host "site Name: $($site.Name)"
```

But does not print anything just "site name"

Comment: The error tells you the exact problem. Powershell has no idea what `Get-SPOFile` is. Is that supposed to be in some installed application/tools? Or were you trying to install a module? How did you hear about this command? That location should also provide information on how to make that command available to you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The term 'Get-SPOList' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75126977/the-term-get-spolist-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function-scri)

Answer (score 0):

"Get-SPOFile" does not appear to be a cmdlet for SharePoint Online.
You can refer this article to see all cmdlets for SharePoint Online.

Here is the powershell to get site name:

```
#Parameters
$AdminSiteURL = "https://crescent-admin.sharepoint.com"
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing"
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL 
 
#Get the Site Collection
$Site = Get-SPOSite -Identity $SiteURL
 
#Get Site Collection Title
Write-host $Site.Title
```

If you are new to SharePoint Online Management PowerSheel, you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online) for a quick start.

Comment: Yes You are right. Do you know what is the command or how to get names of all files in SharePoint site